# How to add RaiseEvent for Delegate Error after conversion from C# to Vb.Net

Tags: vb.net, delegates

I am a newbie to Delegates, and am trying to convert the following C# code into Vb.Net.

Original C# code:

```
    public delegate void delConnectionStatusChanged(EventDrivenTCPClient sender, ConnectionStatus status);
    public event delConnectionStatusChanged ConnectionStatusChanged;
    private ConnectionStatus _ConStat;

    public ConnectionStatus ConnectionState
    {
        get
        {
            return _ConStat;
        }
        private set
        {
            bool raiseEvent = value != _ConStat;
            _ConStat = value;
            if (ConnectionStatusChanged != null && raiseEvent)
                ConnectionStatusChanged.BeginInvoke(this, _ConStat, new AsyncCallback(cbChangeConnectionStateComplete), this);
        }
    }


    private void cbChangeConnectionStateComplete(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        var r = result.AsyncState as EventDrivenTCPClient;
        if (r == null)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Invalid IAsyncResult - Could not interpret as a EDTC object");
        r.ConnectionStatusChanged.EndInvoke(result);
    }
```

Converted to Vb.Net code:

```
    Public Delegate Sub delConnectionStatusChanged(ByVal sender As EventDrivenTCPClient, ByVal status As ConnectionStatus)
    Public Event ConnectionStatusChanged As delConnectionStatusChanged
    Private _ConStat As ConnectionStatus

    Public Property ConnectionState As ConnectionStatus
        Get
            Return _ConStat
        End Get
        Private Set(ByVal value As ConnectionStatus)
            Dim [raiseEvent] As Boolean = value <> _ConStat
            _ConStat = value
            If ConnectionStatusChanged IsNot Nothing AndAlso [raiseEvent] Then ConnectionStatusChanged.BeginInvoke(Me, _ConStat, New AsyncCallback(AddressOf cbChangeConnectionStateComplete), Me)
        End Set
    End Property


    Private Sub cbChangeConnectionStateComplete(ByVal result As IAsyncResult)
        Dim r = TryCast(result.AsyncState, EventDrivenTCPClient)
        If r Is Nothing Then Throw New InvalidOperationException("Invalid IAsyncResult - Could not interpret as a EDTC object")
        r.ConnectionStatusChanged.EndInvoke(result)
    End Sub
```

The full source and conversion can be seen at:
https://pastebin.com/LuvqDvtM

After conversion, I receive the same error for the lines:

```
    r.ConnectionStatusChanged.EndInvoke(result)
```

and

```
    ConnectionStatusChanged.BeginInvoke(Me, _ConStat, New AsyncCallback(AddressOf cbChangeConnectionStateComplete), Me)
```

> Error  BC32022 'Public Event ConnectionStatusChanged As EventDrivenTCPClient.delConnectionStatusChanged' is an event, and cannot be called directly. Use a 'RaiseEvent' statement to raise an event.

So, I learn that the line is an Event, and I can use a 'RaiseEvent' statement instead, but what I don't understand is what the line is actually doing, or what the handler for the 'RaiseEvent' should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C# event, treated like a regular delegate, can be Invoked and BeginInvoked (handlers called asynchronously) whereas VB.Net doesn't seem to do that easily. You can make your own version of that delegate which is not an event, so you can BeginInvoke on it.

```vb
Public Event ConnectionStatusChanged As delConnectionStatusChanged
Private connectionStatusChangedDelegate As delConnectionStatusChanged

'...

Dim raise = value <> _ConStat
_ConStat = value
If raise Then
    connectionStatusChangedDelegate = New delConnectionStatusChanged(Sub(sender, status) RaiseEvent ConnectionStatusChanged(sender, status))
    connectionStatusChangedDelegate.BeginInvoke(Me, _ConStat, New AsyncCallback(AddressOf cbChangeConnectionStateComplete), Me)
End If

'...

Private Sub cbChangeConnectionStateComplete(ByVal result As IAsyncResult)
    Dim r = TryCast(result.AsyncState, EventDrivenTCPClient)
    If r Is Nothing Then Throw New InvalidOperationException("Invalid IAsyncResult - Could not interpret as a EDTC object")
    r.connectionStatusChangedDelegate.EndInvoke(result)
End Sub
```

The delegate is called asynchronously, which just raises the event. This will allow for the event handlers to run asynchronously, and EndInvoke is still called to wait for all the handlers (their calling delegates) to complete.